# Fatal error: Call to undefined function site_url()

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, view, controller

I am using the CodeIgniter framework for PHP. I have created a view named "login.php". Once I

created the view, I then loaded the view inside of a function named "index" which is located

inside a class named "CCI" that extends the Controller but I keep receiving this error: Fatal

error: Call to undefined function site_url() in C:\wamp\www\FinalP_CCI_Clone\system

\application\views\login.php on line 12. I don't understand the issue I an having because the

welcome page loads fine and my second function inside of the "CCI" class loads fine as well.

Here is some of the code:

Controller Files:

```
function CCI()
{
    parent::Controller();
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}

function test()
{
    echo "Testing Data";
}
```

}

/* End of file login.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/controllers/cci.php */

class Welcome extends Controller {

```
function Welcome()
{
    parent::Controller();   
}

function index()
{
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
}

function test()
{
    echo "Testing Data";
}
```

}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/controllers/welcome.php */

Comment: Post more of your code, we can only guess what it could be at this point...

Answer (score 38):

You have to load the helper. The function `site_url()` is provided by the `url` helper, [as described here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Comment: Thank You. Your help is really appreciated. Loading the helper function solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

You can try this:

1. First Load the URL Helper with:

   - `$this->load->helper('url');` or set the following value in `application/config/autoload.php`
   - `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`
2. Then you can show the site url with:

   - `base_url()` (result: http://example.com/) or
   - `site_url()` (result: http://example.com/index.php/)

Note: Results depends on values stored in `application/config/config.php`